# AngularJs:Call directive from controller with some values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have a directive like this

```
app.directive('pagination',function () {
    //custom directive for build pagination
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template:function (elem,attr) {
            console.log(attr.pageCount);
            return 'pagination here';
        }
    };
})
```

and its renderd in my html like this

```
<pagination pageCount="2" currentPage="currentPage"></pagination>
```

But i want to render this after an http call from my controller

```
$http.post('/search',searchParams).then(function (response) {
    //render `pagination` from here 
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

> AngularJS normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine
>   which elements match which directives. We typically refer to
>   directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g.
>   ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to
>   directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using
>   dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).

Try with ng-if..

```
 <pagination page-count="2" current-page="currentPage" ng-if="showPage"></pagination>

   $http.post('/search',searchParams).then(function (response) {
    //render `pagination` from here 
    $scope.showPage = true;
  })
```

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('docsTransclusionExample', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Tobias';
  }])
  .directive('pagination',function () {
    //custom directive for build pagination
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template:function (elem, attr) {
            console.log(attr.pageCount);
           // console.log(attr.pagecount);
            return 'pagination here';
        }
    };
});
})(window.angular);

/*
Copyright 2017 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
*/
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-directive-transclusion-production</title>
  

  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="docsTransclusionExample">
  <div ng-controller="Controller" ng-init="hid = false">{{hid}}
 <pagination ng-if="hid" page-count="2" current-page="currentPage"></pagination>
  <button ng-click="hid=true">Click!</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But i got `pageCount` value as undeifned  in directive `attr.pageCount`

Comment: use directive like above.

Comment: its worked but the `$scope` variable value not getting in directive

Comment: do u want use by attr.val or scope?

Comment: You can't access to the scope in the template function.

Comment: It works however works only first `HTTP` call  but the later calls of API directive not updating the htm